# Site does not appear in combined flair even though I have 200+ reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, combined-flair

My flair only shows Physics SE and Math SE. I want it to make it show world building SE, but I don't know how to make it.

I have [more than 200 reputation there](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8574/jimmy360), and have not hidden it.

Comment: There appears to be a bug, as [your site profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/292397/jimmy360?tab=topactivity) does not display WB among the top accounts, either.  (This is why I thought you didn't have 200 rep there). Did you "hide" WB, by any chance?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, though every time I try to comment on WB in mobile, it claims that I am not a member. I can only vote and comment on WB on my computer.

Comment: Hm... and your network profile, while it shows correct rep=459, says you have 0 answers on WB... A bug.

Comment: @Yes WB is my 2nd highest account.

Comment: maybe is another case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: When looking at [your profile on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221570/jimmy360), your worlbuilding account doesn't show up. But [your WB.SE profile](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8574/jimmy360) shows other communities, which means you aren't explicitly hiding it (that's still true, right?).

Comment: @KevinBrown I don't even know how to hide profiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We aggregate a bunch of information about users in a single table that is then used by the flair generator. It looks like something went wrong with the aggregation in your case. Specifically, we had a record for your Worldbuilding user in that table, but it wasn't correctly attached to your network account.

I fixed that up, so next time the flair regenerates, you should see Worldbuilding on it. As a side benefit, your network profile on stackexchange.com now accurately reflects your badge and question/answer counts.